# initial moment of time, the descendants are shown drilldown

Tags: javascript, highcharts, drilldown

in the `hightcharts` package, I use the `drilldown` mechanism (a tree-like data structure is used), that is, by default, we start the transition from the root of the tree tod its descendants. I want to make it so that at the initial moment of time, the descendants are shown, and we begin to climb from the descendants to the root of the tree. there is such a possibility for `treemap` (setRootnode), but I did not find such a thing for detailing.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your requirement well - let's start with this example of three-level drilldown - http://jsfiddle.net/jd4tgdj3/ - would you like to set the initial rendering of the chart to be focused on the third nested series?

Comment: Yes, everything is so, I want the 3rd level to be shown first

Comment: You can manualy trigger the drilldown event on the initial load: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xcLbns2m/